# Lumen JWT Authentication passes the guard

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt, lumen

I have a strange error using Lumen and JWT Authentication.
We created one mobile app and one web app and we use JWT Auth to authenticate users. We have added some email logging when are some errors so we can hot fix them.

The problem explained:
Sometimes our users pass the JWT Middleware or Guard and the code that is suposed to be auth guarded executes.

This morning we got an SQL error like below:

[image: Error Image]
We have for example a `MobileController` witch extends the main `Controller`. In the main Controller we wrote this code in the `__construct` method

```
if(Auth::check() && Auth::user() == NULL) {
    Auth::logout();
    return abort(401, 'Unauthorized.');
}
```

Even with this above code, users passes the auth guard.

This is our code sample:

routes/web.php

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth:user'], function ($router) {
    $router->group(['prefix' => 'mobile/'], function ($router) {
        $router->post('/company/department', ['uses' => 'MobileController@createCompanyDepartment']);
    });
});
```

app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Assigned table
     * for this model
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $user;
    protected $client;
    protected $company;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user() == NULL) {
            Auth::logout();
            return abort(401, 'Unauthorized.');
        }

        if(Auth::guard('user')->check()) {
            $this->user = Auth::user();
            $this->company = Company::join('languages', 'languages.id', '=', 'companies.language_id')
                ->select('companies.*', 'languages.code as language_code')
                ->find($this->user->company_id);
        } else if(Auth::guard('client')->check()) {
            $this->client = Auth::guard('user')->client();
        } else {
            $this->user = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

app/Http/Controllers/MobileController.php

```
public function createCompanyDepartment(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'  => 'required',
    ]);

    Department::createDepartment($this->user->company_id, $request->input('name'));
    $response = Department::getMobileDepartmentsByCompany($this->user);

    return response()->json($response);
}
```

We expect our unauthorized users to get an Unauthorized 401 error but somethimes they pass the guard. If we try to run the code on local unauthenticated we get Unauthorized 401 message but on production, sometimes our users pass the guard.
Maybe the token expires? This my .env

```
AUTH_GUARD=user
JWT_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
JWT_EXPIRE_AFTER=25920000
```

Anyone experienced this problem or have any ideea why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(!Auth::check() || Auth::user() == NULL) {
    Auth::logout();
    return abort(401, 'Unauthorized.');
}
```

Since `Auth:check()` returns `true` when user **is** authenticated so what you want is to abort if:

> [ User is not authenticated ] OR [ User is `null` ]